# как расшифровать html который выводится requests python?

Tags: python

Отправляю запрос на получения html страницы для дальнейшего парсинга сайта instagram.com, но при выводе html, мне выводится зашифрованный html, который я не смогу спарсить библиотекой bs4
пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    r = s.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tags}/").text

print(r)
```

Comment: Просто это никакой не шифрованный HTML. Это JSON и здесь нет страницы, здесь шифрованный результат запроса.

Comment: А как получить тогда html? Как парсить это дело?

Comment: Вероятно, что страница формируется из множества запросов динамически в браузере. Вроде как, такое дело решается через Selenium